# What is the earliest compatible version of Rails with Bundler 2.0.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

What is the earliest version of Rails I need to use in order to be compatible with bundler 2.0.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rails 5.1.3**

In Rails 5.1.2 and below, the following incompatibility error appears upon running `bundle install`:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 5.1.2) was resolved to 5.1.2, which depends on
      bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (2.0.1)
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
```